# Automating Execution of password protected shell script

Tags: shell

I need to automate the execution of a shell script (ant, java, etc) or even through another shell script

The prompting for username/password is during script runtime

Comment: What do you mean, "password protected shell script"?

Comment: by password protected i mean after running the script you are prompted to enter username then password

Comment: So, the script runs command and some of them pop this password prompt? Find out which one does it and study its documentation, there may be a way to pass login/password as command-line arguments.